# Why don't I have System or Application on top?

Tags: drivers, updates

So for updating drivers and everything it seems that everyone says go to "system" which is at the top, I dont have that. I have "File edit View Go and Help"

I have Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit (idk if it makes a diff) installed on my GT70 dueled with Windows 7. I want to update the drivers for the Ubuntu because it seams my WiFi card isnt working right and i dont even get a signal when i plug in, so i can only get a wireless signal. And few other things but i guess that is my main question right now is how do i get that system or if i cant how do i do a general check for updating all my drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Anything telling you to go to "System" is out of date, that's for older versions of Ubuntu.

You can either click the little gear on the top right and then go to System Settings, or search for and launch the Software Properties to find the driver you need.

See also:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/201524/235

Comment: Cool thanks, but now when i follow that link and go to the Additional drivers and whatnot there's nothing listed? Like there's no drivers being recognized? or what does that mean when there's nothing there?

Comment: Also when i went to the gear and clicked on About this Computer, the graphics is listed as Unknown? I have a NVIDIA Geforce GTX 670M /3GB GDDR5 in this thing just wondering if that will work on here? i found a thing once for what to do to update that driver and get it working but i guess idk if it worked

Comment: @madmike59 You should probably ask that as a new question, something like "How do I get drivers for an NVIDIA Geforce GTX670M" and add all that detail in there, thanks!